# ModuleNotFound : Heroku log showing error on Procfile and fails to launch flask app

Tags: heroku, flask

I am working on a simple flask Todo list web app with postgres database and I tried deploying it to heroku but it is giving me an error saying

> Application error
>   An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

I followed the [Quickstart](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#prepare-the-app) correctly but that did not help

when I check logs by *heroku logs --tail* It says

> ModuleNotFoundError:No module named TodoApp

There are no error logs on command promt also. I can not find any way to check what is going wrong.

This is in my Procfile

```
web: gunicorn TodoApp:app
```

This is in my requirements.txt

```
asn1crypto==0.22.0
certifi==2017.4.17
cffi==1.10.0
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
cryptography==1.9
enum34==1.1.6
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
gunicorn==19.7.1
idna==2.5
ipaddress==1.0.18
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.6
MarkupSafe==1.0
psycopg2==2.7.1
pycparser==2.17
PyJWT==1.5.0
pyOpenSSL==17.0.0
pytz==2017.2
requests==2.18.1
six==1.10.0
SQLAlchemy==1.1.10
twilio==6.4.1
urllib3==1.21.1
Werkzeug==0.12.2
WTForms==2.1
```

This is my todo.py file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template , Response 
from flask import request , jsonify
from models import db ,db1, User
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from message import client
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 
'postgresql://postgres:Abcd@123456@localhost/learningflask'

db.init_app(app)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html",User=User.query.all())

@app.route("/getdata", methods=['GET'])
def get_User(): 
    myuser=User.query.all()
        if myuser =="":
            return 404
        return Response(json.dumps({'taskname':[user.taskname for user in 
myuser]}),  mimetype='application/json')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():

        text=request.form['text']
        if text !="":
            newuser = User(text)
            db.session.add(newuser)
            db.session.commit()
            message = client.messages.create(
            to="",  from_="" , body ="A task has 
been added to your todo list :  "+ text)
            print(message.sid)
            return render_template("index.html",User=User.query.all())

        else:   
            newuser = request.form.getlist('removeId')
            if newuser:
                for n in newuser:
                    User.query.filter_by(uid=n).delete()
                db.session.commit()
                return render_template("index.html",User=User.query.all())
            else:
                edituser = request.form.getlist('editId')
                if edituser:
                    updatedText=request.form['updatedText']
                    for e in edituser:

User.query.filter_by(uid=e).update(dict(taskname=updatedText))
                    db.session.commit()
                    return 
render_template("index.html",User=User.query.all())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)  
    db.create_all()
```

[Here is the folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVzr0.png)

Comment: And what's the code you're deploying? The Procfile? Please, provide [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @LuisOrduz I checked logs correctly and it seems heroku does not understand what TodoApp is which I have declared it in Procfile.

Comment: Could you include the folder structure? If the `todo.py` file is at the top folder, then try `web: gunicorn todo:app` in your Procfile

Comment: @LuisOrduz Please check , I have added the image of my folder structure at the bottom of the post. I tried with todo:app but it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error might be in this line:

> web: gunicorn TodoApp:app

you should use the file name before the `:` and then the flask object you have created.

```
web: gunicorn Todo:app
```

this should work. `toto:app` is the `<filename>:<appname>` .